# Can I Extend an Existing Colorizer or Language in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

What I'd like to do is create an extension that extends HTML support - that is it does everything that HTML support does and more, which includes the following:

1. Syntax Highlighting (colorizer)
2. IntelliSense
3. Format HTML
4. Emmet snippets

These details are listed on this page [HTML Programming in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/html)

Ultimately I would like to create an extension that supports [Liquid Templating](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/) syntax highlighting and auto complete.

I've gotten #1 to work on it's own as a colorizer, and #2 can be accomplished through a language server.

Since Liquid expressions are inserted into HTML documents, the plugin should be built top of/extend HTML support rather than override it. Is this possible?

Comment: Why the downvote? VS Code documentation actually recommends questions be asked to Stackoverflow using the `vscode` tag. https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/supporting/faq#_technical-support

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like this is possible as an extension. Looking at the source code `src\vs\languages\html\common`, if I want to extend an existing built in language support, then I can create a class extension.

For example, `Handlebars` language support is an extension of `HTML` and is implemented thusly:

```
// handlebars.ts
import htmlMode = require('vs/languages/html/common/html');
export class HandlebarsState extends htmlMode.State { ... }
export class HandlebarsMode extends htmlMode.HTMLMode<htmlWorker.HTMLWorker> { ... }
```

So in my particular case, I'll either want to extend HTML or Handlebars (I haven't determined which makes more sense yet) in order to add `Liquid` language support.