# How can I extend an existing language server?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

I am going to create a language server which is pretty similar to javascript.
Is there a way to reuse an existing javascript server for highlighting, auto complete, syntax error, etc?
What I am looking for is to extend `javascript` language server and provide extra keywords, syntax highlighting, auto complete, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I Extend an Existing Colorizer or Language in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38404182/can-i-extend-an-existing-colorizer-or-language-in-vs-code) and [Visual Studio Code Language Extension Inherit Existing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51434014/62576)